# Split list into sub-lists based on integer in string

Tags: python, list

I have a list of strings as such:

```
['text_1.jpg', 'othertext_1.jpg', 'text_2.jpg', 'othertext_2.jpg', ...]
```

In reality, there are more entries than 2 per number but this is the general format. I would like to split this list into list of lists as such:

```
[['text_1.jpg', 'othertext_1.jpg'], ['text_2.jpg', 'othertext_2.jpg'], ...]
```

These sub-lists being based on the integer after the underscore. My current method to do so is to first sort the list based on the numbers as shown in the first list sample above and then iterate through each index and copy the values into new lists if it matches the value of the previous integer.

I am wondering if there is a simpler more pythonic way of performing this task.

Comment: Your post is confusing. You want to get the first integer after the underscore, and sort based on the integer value?

Comment: Yes, but sort based on this value into new sub-lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
import re

lst = ["text_1.jpg", "othertext_1.jpg", "text_2.jpg", "othertext_2.jpg"]

r = re.compile(r"_(\d+)\.jpg")
out = {}
for val in lst:
    num = r.search(val).group(1)
    out.setdefault(num, []).append(val)

print(list(out.values()))
```

Prints:

```py
[['text_1.jpg', 'othertext_1.jpg'], ['text_2.jpg', 'othertext_2.jpg']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Similiar solution to @Andrej:

```
import itertools
import re


def find_number(s):
    # it is said that python will compile regex automatically
    # feel free to compile first
    return re.search(r'_(\d+)\.jpg', s).group(1)


l = ['text_1.jpg', 'othertext_1.jpg', 'text_2.jpg', 'othertext_2.jpg']
res = [list(v) for k, v in itertools.groupby(l, find_number)]
print(res)
#[['text_1.jpg', 'othertext_1.jpg'], ['text_2.jpg', 'othertext_2.jpg']]
```